# Chamets on pesach

Tags: passover, money, riddle

If a Ba'al T'shuva had chamets that was either very important to him, or had a big monitary value and had it in his possesion over pesach before he came back, is there a possible Heter for him so that he won't have to get rid of it? This is just a quizzing question. I already know the answer.

Comment: If you already know an answer to this question, I hope you'll write it up, hopefully citing sources.

Comment: I think chametz is the correct spelling.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked it up, but I heard a shiur about something like this.  Theoretically, if the fellow had a non-Jewish wife who shared joint ownership of his property, then as long as the chametz's value is <50% of everything they own, we can retroactively view the chometz as being hers and the non-chametz his.

Comment: But that is a very specific case.  Most of the time the question is for someone not married to a non-Jew.

Comment: Yes; my understanding is this is a riddle along the lines of "is there any case such that ..."

Answer (score 0):

Shlomo, your father already answered that it is permissible for him to keep and use!

Comment: Hey! If you're going to talk inside baseball, at least tell us the rest of the story! :)

Comment: For those who like some real Lomdus on this topic (sort off see Here)
http://divreichaim.blogspot.com/2008/04/yerusha-of-chameitz-from-someone-who.html

http://divreichaim.blogspot.com/2006/03/chameitz-shavar-alav-hapesach.html

Comment: Probably some of what this inside conversation is about is in here too even though I would love to see a write up on this particular situation